# How to solve Operation not permitted in executing a bash command?

Tags: swift, bash

I want run some bash command from swift but I am getting this massage:

> killall: warning: kill -term 2441: Operation not permitted

How to solve this problem?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Button("Hide Desktop Icons") {
                hideDesktopIconsFunction()
            }
            
        }
        .frame(width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
    }
}


func hideDesktopIconsFunction() {
    
    let task = Process()
    task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/bash")
    task.arguments = ["-c", """
                        defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop -bool false
                        killall Finder
                        """]
    task.launch()
    
}
```

Comment: What user account is your swift program running as / with the permissions of? And do you have any other user accounts logged into the system (say, on account of use of "Switch User" to let an additional user log in without logging the old account out)?

Comment: In general, it would be a Bad Idea to let a service running as user A kill a copy of finder started by User B, and it's right and proper that the OS disallows it. You might think about telling killall to only kill copies of Finder _run by the same user_, as by using the `-u "$USER"` argument.

Comment: (but there's not a completely generic answer to "how to solve operation not permitted", because different kinds of operations have different kinds of permissions requirements; in _some_ cases the answer might be to have the OP start your program as root, but here when you only want to restart the current user's copy of Finder that's clearly not appropriate, and the right answer is to fix your code so it _only_ restarts the current user's copy and doesn't try to restart other copies as well).

Comment: I am the only one using my mac and i have no other user, I can run that command in terminal with typing, the idea of doing this via a button is stop typing and just click.

Comment: Oh, by the way I solved the issue, I delete my sandbox. The command works now

Comment: What you think about this kind of app or program that try run bash under swift? is it a acceptable app or it might be get crashed by end user because of privacy or something like that.

Comment: If the problem is solved, please answer your own question in the Answer field, or delete the question.

Comment: By the way, there is already a convenient app that turns off Finder Desktop icons for you.

Comment: @matt: The name of the app please?

Comment: http://www.bresink.com/osx/0TinkerTool/screenshots.html Note that this app does not require turning off the sandbox.

Comment: This is so good thanks, this app use bash or what? because the only way of hide the desktop icons is with terminal, if this app has the sandbox, then how the bash command get lunched?

Comment: @matt: I downloaded the app and I am using it, but I cannot find the hide/show desktop icons, is it in deferent name in app?

Comment: It is shown in the first screenshot on the page that I linked you to. On my machine it is called Disable Desktop features.

Comment: Another thing to be aware of is that you don't need to write a whole Swift GUI app just to make a double-clickable that toggles this setting. You can do it with a Terminal document (or, for that matter, with AppleScript).

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my App Sandbox and the command works now.